# Need help to fix the below packages error

Tags: grub2, dpkg, gdm

```
zeppelin@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 linux-headers-5.4.0-51 linux-headers-5.4.0-51-generic linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-51-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up docker.io (19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package docker.io (--configure):
 installed docker.io package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up tzdata (2020d-0ubuntu0.20.04) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
 installed tzdata package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up ca-certificates (20201027ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 installed ca-certificates package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configur
ation of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker.io
 tzdata
 grub-pc
 ca-certificates
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 snapd
 google-chrome-stable
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Comment: and try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Yes i did and getting the same error